# Video tag with MP4 does not display in Apple Safari

Tags: html, video, safari, mp4

On my website i have a code for video tag that looks like this:

```html
 <div class='videoRoundedBorder videoSelected' id='rozw1border' >
        <div id='filmPierwszy' >
          <video id='film1video' autoplay class='aFilm filmSelected' width="251" height="156" loop onmouseover='hoverFilm(1);'  onfocus='hoverFilm(1);' onmouseout='hoveroutFilm(1);' onblur='hoveroutFilm(1);' onclick='window.location.href = "?kategoria=firma&amp;oferta=stworzenie-strony-internetowej"' poster="http://websoul.pl/newdesign/videos/tworzenie-stron-www.png" >
            <source src="http://websoul.pl/newdesign/videos/tworzenie-stron-www.mp4?v=8" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="http://websoul.pl/newdesign/videos/tworzenie-stron-www.ogg?v=7" type="video/ogg" />
            <source src="http://websoul.pl/newdesign/videos/tworzenie-stron-www.webm?v=7" type='video/webm' />
            
          Stworzenie<br/>strony WWW / modernizacja          </video> 
        </div>
```

It works fine in FF, Chrome, IE 10 and on latest Androids. But on my PC with Windows 7 in Safari 5.1.7 (latest for Windows) it does not display.

Not only video is displayed. There is no error in Safari console and no indication of trying to download the video whatsoever.

I was reading several tutorials about doing the right tag and encode video properly but i don't know if this is an issue of the Win Safari not working properly or the issue also occurs on iPhones and iPads since i don't have ones.

What to do to make this video display properly on iDevices ?

Comment: Ok, I've tried this on Safari 5.1.7 on my Windows 7 machine and the video plays just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari requires QuickTime to be installed in order to play HTML5 video (yes really) so perhaps ensure you have it installed? (normally a Mac system would have, but perhaps a Windows system does not)

Comment: I had it installed. I've reinstalled qt and safari and it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

"Safari supports the `video` and `audio` media elements on iOS 3.0 and later and in Safari 3.1 and later on the desktop (Mac OS X and Windows)" - [apple.developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Try deleting the tags like `onblur` and `onfocus` in your video tag. Try the standard video tag to test it.

edit:

Maybe try to add the quicktime plugin: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/samplecode/HTML_video_example/Listings/ac_quicktime_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007723-ac_quicktime_js-DontLinkElementID_3)

add:

```
<script src="ac_quicktime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and maybe use a .mov movie like this:

```
<source src="myMovie.mov" type="video/quicktime">
```